# The Existence of $A^{-1}$ From the Characteristic Polynomial of A

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix $A$ has the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^3+x-1$, is it true that $\det(A)×(-1)^n=-1$ where ($n=$the dimension of $A$. Is there any intuition behind this result, assuming that I have it correctly?

Comment: Is $p(x)$ the characteristic or the minimal polynomial? Because if it's the characteristic polynomial, then the fact that it's cubic means that the matrix is $3\times3$ -- so what's the point of denoting its known size as "$n$"?

Comment: My feeling is that "intuition" is fairly hard to come by. Of course the constant term in the characteristic polynomial is equal to $(-1)^n \det(A)$ since the last term is a product of eigenvalues (an algebraic argument), but I'm curious to know if somebody has geometric intuition (e.g. determinants relating to volumes).

Comment: @zipirovich $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial. The $n$ was to denote an explicit formula.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about interpreting the actual *value* of coefficients of the characteristic polynomial geometrically, (the characteristic polynomial has a very algebraic flavour), but you can definitely see why the constant term affects invertibility.

In your example, if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(x) = x^3 + x - 1$, then by Cayley-Hamilton we have $A^3 + A - 1 = 0$, which we can rearrange into $A(A^2 + 1) = 1$, and so we find that $A^{-1} = A^2 + 1$. It should be clear we can do this whenever the constant term is nonzero.

Comment: If the constant term is zero then $0$ is an eigenvalue anyways.

Comment: @percusse Of course there are a lot of ways to see any result in maths: the question asked about seeing the existence of the inverse from the characteristic polynomial itself: I think this is a nice way (and even gives an explicit formula for the inverse).

Comment: As far as I understand the question is about the determinant of a matrix with already given form. I don't see how it is related to having nonzero constant term.